# Mockito: how to verify method call of a singelton class from another singelton class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, singleton, mockito

I am new to Unit testing and Mockito, how to write test code for given code snippet which is singleton.

**1. I want to write unit test for class XYZ.**
**2. I want to verify the whether methods get called or not.**
**3. I want to write test code to check state of temp variable.**
**4. I want to write test code for private method calculator also.**

class ABC is singleton and has two fields num and square.

```
class ABC{
      private static ABC instance;
      private int num;
      private int square;

      private ABC() {}

      public static ABC getInstance() {
          if (instance == null) {
              instance = new ABC();
          }
          return instance;
      }

      public int getSquar() {
          return square;
      }

      public void setSquar(int square) {
          this.square = square;
      }

      public int getNum() {
          return num;
      }

      public void setNum(int num) {
          this.num = num;
      }
}
```

class XYZ which is singleton is calling getter and setter from class ABC is also singleton.

```
class XYZ{
     private static XYZ instance;
     private int result;

     private XYZ(){}

     public static XYZ getInstance(){
          if (instance == null) {
              instance = new XYZ();
          }
          return instance;
     }

     public void calculateSquare(){
         ABC.getInstance().setNum(5);
         int n = ABC.getInstance().getNum();
         result = calculator(n);
         ABC.getInstance().setSquare(result);

     }  

     private int calculator(int n){
         return n*n;
     }
}
```

here i am calling calculateSquare method of class XYZ.

```
XYZ.getInstance().calculateSquare();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm afraid I'll have to flag this as "too broad" or maybe even "off-topic".  At least show some effort and post specific questions to possible issues you encounter and you'll get all the help you need.You can't really expect to have your unit tests written for you by simply posting it on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Oceans this code snippet is dummy, i just wanted to know how can we achieve the above 4 question with the help of dummy code.

Comment: Singleton is a well-known anti-pattern, and one of the reasons is that it makes real unit tests and mocking impossible. Use dependency injection. Or write a test that tests XYZ and ABC at the same time.

Comment: As JB Nizet already said, Singletons are a very bad idea. In this case, you would need to use PowerMockito to mock static methods - but PowerMockito is primarily, if you ask me, something to work around bad code. It's preferable to make the code better.

Comment: @BlackHawk if you find my answer useful / satisfying then please consider accepting it, thx. Or comment what is missing.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to answer

> Mockito: How to verify a method call in a singleton triggered by a method invocation of another singleton?

with respect to

```
XYZ.getInstance().calculateSquare();
```

assuming you only want to use Mockito and JUnit.

***Answer***: Your "dummy code" is the perfect example of untestable code.

- Your example code does not expose any observable behaviour to the outside. The "outside" would be your yet-to-be-written surrounding test code exercising your "dummy code". (So) you cannot make any assertions (JUnit/Hamcrest) about your "dummy code".
- By using Singletons you make it impossible to control the "inner state" of your "dummy code" while it is under test. (So) you cannot make any verification (Mockito) about the behaviour of your "dummy code".
- You cannot test `private` methods directly because you cannot invoke them. If you feel the need to test a `private` method then it should not be `private`.

  Private methods hide the internal implementation against which you should never write any tests. Write tests against the public API testing for the expected behaviour and not how that behaviour is implemented (which may change whenever for whatever reasons which then breaks your tests easily).

If you want to test your code then you have to design / code it such that *it is testable*. JUnit / Mockito cannot make untestable code testable for you.

---

Hints on what to do:

**Replace the Singleton** approach with a simple constructor *taking any dependent collaborator* required for the instance to do its work. Which results into

```
public Xyz(final Abc yourCollaborator) {
    this.collaborator = yourCollaborator;
}
```

**Using Mockito** you can create a Mock or Spy instance of your `Abc.class`. You need such a mocked Abc instance to pass it into your Xyz constructor for your verification purposes. Like this:

```
@Test
public void calculateSquareShouldSetNumTo5() throws Exception {
    Abc mockedAbc = Mockito.mock(Abc.class);
    Xyz xyz = new Xyz(mockedAbc);
    
    // method under test
    xyz.calculateSquare();
    
    Mockito.verify(mockedAbc).setNum(5); // expect setNum(5) to be called once
}
```

To actually **make an assertion** about your implementation you need a real instance of your Abc class. Because it is the "part" where you can observe the effect of your `calculateSquare()` method call. (Note that you cannot use a Mockito mocked Abc instance for that!) Your test might look like this:

```
 @Test
 public void calculateSquareShouldAlwaysResult25() throws Exception {
     Abc abc = new Abc();
     Xyz xyz = new Xyz(abc);

     // method under test
     xyz.calculateSquare();

     assertThat(abc.getSquare(), is(25));
 }
```

In fact, the last test could also be written for your "dummy code" as is:

```
 @Test
 public void calculateSquareShouldAlwaysResult25() throws Exception {
     // method under test
     XYZ.getInstance().calculateSquare();

     assertThat(ABC.getInstance().getSquare(), is(25));
 }
```

***So why are Singletons still bad for testing?*** Singletons cannot be easily replaced with a "placeholder" instance for your testing purposes. Such a placeholder can be your special test implementation of Abc `TestAbc extends Abc`, or a Mockito mocked Abc instance.

Finally, ***if you would have written your tests first*** (!) you would have never ever written your "dummy code" in this way.

**Disclaimer:** Above code is intended to give you some idea on how to approach testing and what kind of changes your "dummy code" needs to make it testable. This does not imply meaningful tests or that these examples compile as they are.